# Samba's testparm returned error 1: Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf Error loading services

Tags: networking, samba, shared-folders

[Here is an image of error showing when creating share](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kb61M.png)

Any one plz help me to resolve this isssue
Tried Bing & ChatGPT Nothing works

Comment: Do you get any more detailed information if your run `testparm` or `testparm -s` from the command line?

Comment: $ testparm
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
Error loading services.

Comment: $ testparm -s
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
Error loading services.

Comment: So does `/etc/samba/smb.conf` exist? is it readable (mode `-rw-r--r--`)?

Comment: the file doesn't exist